# React send AJAX request inside input onChange

Tags: ajax, reactjs

This is my **SearchForm.js**, on change input `keywords` I need to send AJAX request with value of this input on other server with, get some values and use them for autocomplete this input. Is it possible at all? How to make it?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class SearchForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
       keywords: '',
       city: '',
       date: ''     
      }

      //this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
      //this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)

      this.handleKeywordsChange = this.handleKeywordsChange.bind(this);
      this.handleCityChange = this.handleCityChange.bind(this);  
     }

    handleKeywordsChange(e) {      
        this.setState({
          keywords: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleCityChange(e) {      
        this.setState({
          city: e.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <form className='form search-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-row">
                  <div className="form-group col-md-5">
                    <label htmlFor="keywords">Keywords</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="keywords" id="keywords" placeholder="Keywords" onChange={this.handleKeywordsChange} value={this.state.keywords} />

                  </div>

                  <div className="form-group col-md-5">
                    <label htmlFor="city">City</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City" onChange={this.handleCityChange} value={this.state.city} />
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label htmlFor="date">Date</label>
                    <select className="form-control" name="date" id="date" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.date}>
                      <option>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                      <option>3</option>
                      <option>4</option>
                      <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                 </div>

                 <div className="form-row">
                     <div className="form-group col-md-12">
                        <input id='formButton' className='btn btn-primary' type='submit' placeholder='Send' />
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export { SearchForm }
```

Comment: It's nicer to review and answer questions if you try to minimize the code to be the smallest set of code that demonstrates your situation, this has a lot of fluff. Also mixing 4 and 2 space indentation is annoying to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use axios api to call api and fetch data

```
onKeyUp(e) {
  axios.get('/seachdata?keywords='+e.target.value)
  .then(function (response) {
     this.setState({autosearchresponse: response.data})
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

search data set in this.state.autosearchresponse
you can use autosearch response as html

```
 {this.state.autosearchresponse.map((value, i)=>
  <div key={i}>{value}</div>    
)}
```

bind onKeyUp function to input

Comment: Do I need to include axios in my SearchForm.js ?

Comment: first install "npm install axios " and include like "import axios from 'axios';

Comment: How can I add `User-Agent` header in ajax request?

Comment: axios.get(URL, { headers: { 'User-Agent': 'Chrome' } })